# How do you make a <div> less than 13px tall in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

How do you make DIVs very short in IE6? No matter if I use 0.3em or 3px, IE6 forces a minimum of 13px.

**IE6**

[image: IE6]

**Firefox 3.6.13** (looks quite similar in all other modern browsers)

[image: FF]

**HTML**

```
<div id="fileProgressBar" style="display:none">
    <div id="fileProgressFill"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fileProgressBar {
    height: 0.3em;
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #333,
        #666
    );
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #333),
        color-stop(1, #666)
    );
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

    #fileProgressFill {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        background: #0088cc;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(
            top,
            #0099e5,
            #006699
        );
        background: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top,
            left bottom,
            color-stop(0, #0099e5),
            color-stop(1, #006699)
        );
    }
```

**Javascript**

Javascript reveals the file progress bar at appropriate times and updates the file progress fill as the movie is playing. But this bug is not a JS issue, so I won't post the JS code.

Comment: Either `font-size`, `margin`, or/and `padding`. PS: IE sucks :)

Comment: I use overflow: hidden; instead of font-size: 0;.

Comment: Overflow works in this case, but not in all. If you have a thin slider control with a knob, the knob would be chopped off if overflow on. In this case, you'd have to use the font-size:0 trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was overcomplicating this a bit:

Just do:

```
#fileProgressBar {
    height: 3px;
    font-size: 0;
    ..
}
```

---

<strike>To fix it in IE6, to `#fileProgressBar`, add `font-size: 3px`. However, this makes it look wrong in normal browsers. So, the easiest way is fix it is to either apply that style in a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), or to add it like this, using a [CSS hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack) (which fortunately does validate) so only IE6 can see it:</strike>

```
* html #fileProgressBar {
    font-size: 3px
}
```

I'm going to see if there's a neater way to fix this.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to strike out that stuff instead of removing it because I figured the links could still be helpful.